# How to filter by value of an extension in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to save some data to events using open extensions, and retrieve an event by the value of the extension I saved. I unfortunately couldn't find any documentation around it, and not sure if it is possible.

I am sure that the extensions are saved properly because when I use make a request to this URL in graph explorer it returns the data properly attached to the events:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events?$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'Com.MyCompany.prop_id')&$expand=Extensions($filter=id eq 'Com.MyCompany.prop_id')`

Now what I want to do is to filter upon the value of the extension. For example, if I have 3 events that I created, I have different `Com.MyCompany.prop_id` values for each of them, say 1,2,3. What I want to do is to get back only the event with `Com.MyCompany.prop_id = 3`.

My tries:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events?$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/value eq '3')&$expand=Extensions($filter=id eq 'Com.MyCompany.prop_id')`

and

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events?$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'Com.MyCompany.prop_id' and f/value eq '3')&$expand=Extensions($filter=id eq 'Com.MyCompany.prop_id')`, and some other tries that I don't remember.

Most of them returned `RequestBroker--ParseUri: Could not find a property named 'value' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Extension'.` or some other error.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It looks like it may not be possible to filter on non-`id` properties when using Open Extensions, unfortunately. It might be worth a look at [Schema Extensions][1], instead.


More info:
https://www.techmikael.com/2017/09/which-schema-to-use-in-microsoft-graph.html


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/schemaextension?view=graph-rest-1.0